# Thread local variables and inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am trying to use a thread local variable in inline assembly, but when I see the diassembled code, It appears that the compiler doesn't generate the right code. For the following inline code, where **saved_sp** is *globally* declared as `__thread long saved_sp`,

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq %rsp, saved_sp\n\t");
```

The disassembly looks like the following.

```
mov    %rsp,0x612008
```

Which is clearly not the right thing, because I know that gcc uses the **fs** segment for thread local variables. It should had generated something like

```
mov %rsp, fs:somevalue
```

which it is not. Why is that so? Is using thread local variables in inline assembly problematic?

Comment: I don't think gcc anyhow modifies your inline assembly code. Most probably you have to explicitly specify the segment override prefix. Try inserting `".byte 0x64\n\t"` before `"movq %rsp, saved_sp\n\t"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple thing that would surely work is to take a pointer to the thread local variable, and write to it.
Your compiler will surely do `long *saved_fp_p = &saved_fp` correctly, and inline assembly will only deal with `saved_fp_p`, which is a local variable.

You can also use gcc's input and output syntax:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "mov %%rsp, 0(%0)" : : "r" (&saved_sp)
);
```

This puts the compiler in charge of resolving the address of saved_fp, and the assembly code gets it in a register.

We found out that this also works,

```
__asm__ __volatile__ asm ("mov %rsp,%0" : "=m" (saved_sp))
```

Comment: This is a good clever solution, but I would prefer to write directly to saved_sp, rather than using a register to point it.

Comment: perhaps `asm ("mov %rsp,%0" : : "m" (saved_fp))` will work. The important part is to let the compiler, not the assembler, handle the saved_fp variable. The compiler can surely do it correctly, the assembler seems to do it badly.